# Integration of feature file, steps.rb and env.rb through cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

i have created a feature file to run in cucumber and i have the steps definition file in ruby extension but whenever i run the feature file the ruby file is not called into action. The env.rb file too is present. Provide solutions.

Comment: You'll have to provide much more information for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: I agree with Dave! If your Ruby file is not being called at all it is probably not on the load path so you need to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the '-r' switch to run your tests eg. cucumber -r features/....

This will force cucumber to load the step definitions which are present in your support and step definition directories which are under the 'features' root directory.

You can alternatively set "-r features" in the config/cucumber.yml file at the end of your profile (std_opts)